# Restart nm-applet 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

Unity + 16.04

Is there any command I can use in Terminal to restart the `nm-applet` ? There is a bug in 16.04 which make `nm-applet` disappear from the panel when resuming from **suspend**.

Comment: You have already know the answer - just run `nm-applet` in terminal.

Comment: Is it ? I will try and update. Currently, I use `killall nm-applet; nohup nm-applet &`

Comment: Your variant is correct. I mean that `nm-applet` does not accept arguments from console.

Comment: Which one should I use ?

Comment: `killall nm-applet; nohup nm-applet &` and if it is possible please report bug about your problem or subscribe to the [existing one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bugs?field.searchtext=suspend&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=&orderby=-id&start=0).

Comment: There is already a bug report dating as back as 05/16 . Thanks.

Comment: Has there been any progress on this bug?